# How can i ignore a annotation of cache on a Domain?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables, table A and table B.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "A")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class A implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
        private Long id;

        @NotNull
        @Size(max = 250)
        @Column(name = "name", length = 250, nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String name;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aitems")
        @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
        private Set<B> bItems = new HashSet<>()

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class B implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 250, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("bItems")
    private A aItems;
```

I can create post request for table A and Table B, but if i create a post for A , and after a post for B with relation to the item A that was before created , i want to be able do send a Get request to A and see the B item, but i can only seem them after i reboot my aplication, because when i do the first A post it's stays on cache without any B item.
How can i ignore this without removing it from the domain.

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your implementation, you may be able to take advantage of `@CacheEvict`. Check out the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html), they show you how you can evict A's cache when a POST to B occurs.

Hope this helps

Comment: All my implementation does not uses @cacheable and for the search i did evict only results when cacheable is used to save cache.